# How to render inside elements of a custom component with react typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a question regarding the element which is inside custom parent component, how to catch it and render it.

For example:
Parent

```
interface ComponentProps{
 message: string;
}
export default MyComponent: FunctionComponent = <ComponentProps>(props: ComponentProps) => {
render (
<div>{props.message}</div>
)
}
```

Now, imagine i call this component with inside elements, like this

```
<MyComponent message='Test'>
<div>How to render this div inside MyComponent, how to catch it?</div>
</MyComponent>
```

So, the question is how to accept this  inside MyComponent and render it as wel?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The `children` property aka `props.children` contains the child elements that the component wraps.

Comment: https://react.dev/learn/passing-props-to-a-component#passing-jsx-as-children

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a more practical example demonstrating the `children` property of a functional component in React.

The wrapper component will return a wrapped version of the children passed to it and display a message alert box at the top.

```
import { ReactNode } from "react";

export type ComponentMessageWrapperProps = {
  message: string;
  children: ReactNode;
};

/* Wraps children inside of a border with a message at the top. */
export default const ComponentMessageWrapper = ({
  children,
  message,
}: ComponentMessageWrapperProps) => {
  return (
    <div className="ComponentWrapper">
      <div className="message">{message}</div>
      <>{children}</>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
import ComponentMessageWrapper from './ComponentMessageWrapper.tsx';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ComponentMessageWrapper message="Test">
        <div>This DIV is rendered inside of ComponentMessageWrapper</div>
      </ComponentMessageWrapper>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Here is a working JSX snippet of the TSX code above above.

```js
const { Fragment } = React;

/* Wraps children inside of a border with a message at the top. */
const ComponentMessageWrapper = ({ children, message }) => {
  return (
    <div className="ComponentWrapper">
      <div className="message">{message}</div>
      <Fragment>
        {children}
      </Fragment>
    </div>
  );
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ComponentMessageWrapper message="Test">
        <div>This DIV is rendered inside of ComponentWrapper</div>
      </ComponentMessageWrapper>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(document.getElementById("root"))
  .render(<App />);
```

```css
.ComponentWrapper {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border: thin solid #700;
}

.ComponentWrapper .message {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  border: thin solid #700;
  background: #EAA;
  color: #700;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

this should be pretty straight forward,

your can have a property called `children` with the type of `React.ReactNode` and use this children on the `MyComponent`

```
interface ComponentProps{
 message: string;
 children: React.ReactNode;
}
export default function MyComponent(props: ComponentProps) => {
render (
<>
  <div>{props.message}</div>
  <div>{props.children}</div> 
</>

);
}
```

the place where u are using this

```
<MyComponent message='Test'>
<div>How to render this div inside MyComponent, how to catch it?</div>
</MyComponent>
```

with the above changes your custom div with text "How to render this div inside MyComponent, how to catch it?"  is going to rendered within MyComponent